# Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

This is quite frustrating. I am simply trying to create a dynamic text and put some text into it on runtime.

I get this error though

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at MethodInfo-1()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

I have a text object named textLabel, which is inside a movieclip named MC_state.
I get it because I use:

```
MC_state.textLabel.text = "asdasd";
```

And I wish I knew what the problem was. I have other objects set up quite the same way which don't give me that problem. I just don't know how debug that.

Thanks!

Comment: From what you've given, I will guess: You are attempting to access textLabel before it has been initialized. Where are you attempting to assign to the text property?

Comment: The keyframe where MC_State resides is further on the timeline, from where the code is. (code at frame 10, MC's first keyframe on 35). I copied the frames so that vertically all objects have a frame right underneath the code, I think it solved the problem. Is that the way to go about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that there is no object somewhere along `MC_state.textLabel.text`, so either flash cannot find `MC_state`, or `textLabel`inside `MC_state` or (unlikely) `text` inside `MC_state.textLabel`.

If I may venture a guess though, I think you're seeing this because this happened:

you have somewhere a movieclip called `MC_state` that has more than one frames. You tied to do gotoAndStop or gotoAndPlay to a frame that has the textfield called `textLabel` and that's the text you're trying to change.

The problem, and it comes up often for people transitioning from AS2, is that when you execute the gotoAndPlay/gotoAndStop function, the movieClip doesn't update right away, this happens iin the render phase. The code after that function however executes right away, so the movieclip is still at the old frame.

there are two ways you can handle it

- set up a event handler that updates the render event, and change the text then. You can hurry the stage rendering by running `stage.invalidate` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953618/error-1009-in-as3/7036004#7036004)
- the other (better) option is to have the text in all the frames, and have it hidden or invisible, that way you can access it at any time.

Comment: I copied the frames so that I have an object at that frame. Now I can't see the text, which is another problem. This is frustrating

Comment: you could have the text visible in all frames and set the text visibility through code, shouldn't be an issue since you're switching between the frames using code anyway.  Also you can change the properties of the textfield in the different keyframes, you only need to make sure that the textfield is present in every frame.

Comment: I noticed that the antialiasing can pose difficulties, switched to Use device fonts, but that looks horrible

Comment: device fonts won't work on a machine if it doesn't have the font.
Embedding the fonts can be tricky, but there are many resources out there dealing with that. http://marumushi.com/news/embedding-fonts-in-as3